# Basic Geometry: Partitions and Intersections

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

*Once more unto the breach, dear friends, once more!*

So I'm currently working on a problem which I have somehow been able to simplify to the point where if I can simply prove that if three lines each partition a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into **two pairs of equal parts**, then the portion of the compact set contained in the "triangle of intersections" between these lines must be zero.

To illustrate, consider this figure:

[image]

Where we know that

$$ \begin{align}
A & = D_1 + D_2 \\\\
B_1 + B_2 & = C_1 + C_2 \\\\
B_2 & = C_1 + D_1 \\\\
C_2 & = B_1 + D_1 \\\\
A + C_1 & = B_2 + D_2 \\\\
A + B_1 & = C_2 + D_2
\end{align} $$

If I can just prove that $D_1 = 0$, then *everything would work*. Alas, after hours of banging my head against the wall (and also doing some computations, mind you), I am unable to get it to work.

Thus, I appeal to you.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: The description "three lines each partition a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 into equal parts," doesn't seem to match the equations.  It seems more like each pair of line partition the set into two pairs of equal parts.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No, you are quite right. That is exactly what I intended to convey. I shall edit the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations can be solved for $A,B_1, B_2$ in terms of the $C$'s and $D$'s:
$$ \eqalign{A &= D_1 + D_2\cr B_1 &= C_2 - D_1\cr
     B_2 &= C_1 + D_1}$$
You'll want $C_2 \ge D_1$ so $B_1 \ge 0$, but otherwise $C_1, \ldots, D_2$ can be arbitrary nonnegative numbers.

Comment: At first I was baffled that this might be the case, but plugging the numbers into Excel convinced me that Mr Israel is entirely right in his statement. Let $A=B_2 = C_2 = 20\%$, $B_1 = C_1 = D_1 = D_2 = 10\%$, and all the maths actually checks out perfectly well. This is most annoying, but alas, I cannot argue with maths. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Um, you should just have tried with a non-rectangular shape...

[image: the intersection of the vertical and horizontal lines that halves a tromino does not lie on one of the diagonal lines that halves the tromino]

Clearly, the green (vertical) and blue (horizontal) lines halve the tromino, but the red (diagonal) line does not, and you would have to translate it a bit to make it halve the tromino.